# Is it possible to control media player quality?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I download video with:

```
mPlayer.setDataSource("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ellovidsout/1232/9/1423065486.mp4.m3u8")
```

Header contains following data:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=532000,RESOLUTION=400x224,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.2"
400k_1423065486.mp4.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1273000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
1000k_1423065486.mp4.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2476000,RESOLUTION=1024x576,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
2000k_1423065486.mp4.m3u8
```

Can I manually force media player to play only video with resolution 400x224 for example? (Except manually alerating url adding quality code to id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [selectTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#selectTrack(int)) and [getTrackInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getTrackInfo()) Therefore, it doesn't work properly for all devices and Android OS version.

It might be helpfull to use [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html) . Here you can check the [demo app](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/demo).

Comment: like. I win test it