# How to set different video quality like auto, 360p,720p etc in videoview in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, android-videoview

guys i am stuck in quality of videos in videview. How to change video quality in videview. Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `HLS` to stream videos I recommend you to use `ExoPlayer` and handle it server-side, also you can find out how to set video quality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30355533/3048424).